# Is the main Grand Central Dispatch queue serial or concurrent?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

Suppose I call `dispatch_async()` three times in order:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
         ^{
             [self doOne];
});

// some code here

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
         ^{
             [self doTwo];
});

// more code here

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
         ^{
             [self doThree];
});
```

Will this always be executed like

`[self doOne]`, `[self doTwo]`, then `[self doThree]`, or is the order is guaranteed?

In this case, the question probably is if the main queue is serial or concurrent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `dispatch_get_main_queue`
>
> Returns the **serial** dispatch queue associated with the application’s
>   main thread.

so the main queue is a *serial* queue, and `[self doOne]`, `[self doTwo]`, `[self doThree]` are executed sequentially in that order.

Comment: Also, it has to be serial since the blocks run on the same thread. There is no way that a single thread can run multiple blocks concurrently.

Comment: @Rob Yes, but the blocks submitted to the main queue will be executed in the main thread. That is the whole point of the main queue. Queues don't execute blocks, that always happens in some thread. Usually a private thread managed by GCD, but the main thread for the main queue.

Comment: @Sven You misunderstood me. My point is simply to clarify that this is true for the main queue, not applicable to queues in general.

Answer (score 4):

[Concurrency Programming Guide, About Dispatch Queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2):

> The main dispatch queue is a globally available **serial** queue that executes tasks on the application’s main thread. [emphasis mine]